# How to Hide the Smart Filter Bar in the Overview Page (SAP Fiori Element)

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

The [SAP Fiori documentation for the Overview Page](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/overview-page/#dynamic-page) indicates that it's possible to set up a Dynamic Page Variant that will hide the Smart Filter Bar. At the technical SAPUI5 level, how would one actually do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to hide the Smart Filter Bar from the Overview Page (OVP), then remove the following properties from `manifest.json`:

- `globalFilterEntityType` from `sap.ovp`
- `description` from `sap.app`

Comment: **NB:** it also works if you just set the attributes' values to an empty string.

Comment: **Caveat:** for Fiori schema compliance, I needed to delete the `description` and set the `globalFilterEntityType` to an empty string

Answer (score 0):

I left the app description in sap.app as is, and then put an empty string in globalFilterEntityType. That worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).